# What is the name for a magma which is neither a quasigroup nor a semigroup yet has both an identity and inverses?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, inverse, magma

Is there a name which is more specific than `unital magma' for a magma whose only requirements are that it should have both an identity **and** (L/R symmetric) inverses for all elements?

The following Cayley Table is the simplest non-trivial object of the type I am interested in, though of course you could make much more complicated examples:

```
  | 0 1 2
--+------
0 | 0 1 2
1 | 1 0 1
2 | 2 1 0
```

This object it is not a quasigroup (or a loop) as the table is not a Latin Square.

This object is not a semigroup as it is not associative.  For example: `(1*1)*2 = 0*2 = 2` while `1*(1*2) = 1*1 = 0`.

It does, however, have an identity, 0.  Furthermore, every element has a unique inverse (which is itself).

For what it's worth the multiplication rule is `a*b = |a-b|` on the set `{0,1,2}`.

A part of an older question ( [Magma with inverse and identity yet not a quasigroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322303/magma-with-inverse-and-identity-yet-not-a-quasigroup) ) could be interpreted as requesting an answer to the same question I am asking today. However, the one answer which that question received did not answer the bit which I would like to see answered. I have therefore judged that it's helpful to ask the missing part here more succinctly to maximise the chance that it gets an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.05461.pdf), for example, uses the terms

- *inverse property magma*
- *magma with inverses*

for properties defined in two different ways. The second one means a magma where each element has a unique inverse element.

Also, beware because the finite groupoid as in the Cayley table in your question is definitey not cancellative:
$$1*0=1*2=2*1=0*1,$$
but $2\ne 0$.

Comment: In the opening sentence of the above paper (not including the abstract) it makes clear that it defines the word magma differently than I intended in my question. However, that paper is clear that what *it* calls a magma is what my question calls a `unital magma', and then it goes on to add the inverses to its magmas, and so that paper is certainly defining things of the sort of thing I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

"Cancellative unital magma" is more-specific than "unital magma".  This phrase would technically be a valid answer to the question, as invertibility implies cancellation, but I would prefer something more specific.  I'd suggest "Invertible unital magma" except that I cannot find any evidence that this is a term that is in use outside of this post, whereas at least "Cancellative magma" has appears from time to time, [such as here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Magma&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop).

Comment: I agree that this is not a good answer for the reason suggested by @MattAllegro in his answer.